# Is there a difference between these two? distinct table.* vs select *

Tags: sql, sql-server, field, distinct

I have to remove a single field from the result set and I want to create identical results. What is the proper syntax for replicating

```
select distinct t1.* from table1 t1
```

while specifying the fields explicitly?

Comment: What makes you think SQL won't return duplicate data if it's present in the table?

Comment: `distinct ` remove duplicay when select row are same

Comment: SQL absolutely returns duplicates if they exist.

Comment: Please don't make tables without primary keys :-) With a primary key, clearly the two queries would be equivalent.

Comment: You might take a look at the documentation for sql server. It pretty clearly explains what the DISTINCT argument does. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx

Comment: In both versions you don't need to specify the table alias since there *is* only one table ... and YES, MySql will list duplicates if you don't include the `distinct` keyword.

Comment: I just thought I remembered reading it somewhere. Thanks for the clarification. My ultimate goal is to remove one of the columns from the table in the result set, so I have to explicitly specify every column. I'm wondering how I can create the same result. 

    `select distinct f1, distinct f2, distinct f3, ....`

doesn't seem like it would be correct. How can I replicate the behavior while specifying the columns specifically?

Comment: You only specify the `distinct` keyword once!

Comment: `DISTINCT` works across the entire row, not for individual columns.

Comment: The distinct keyword is applied to every field in the select.

Comment: @cars10 so `select distinct f1, f2, f3,....` would be the same as `select distinct t1.*`?

Comment: they are totally same queries **if you have a primary key on your table**.

Comment: Your question has now changed and it doesn't make any sense now. What are trying to do?

Comment: Existing code exists in the form `select distinct t1.* from table1 t1`. I need to remove one of the fields from this query (I don't want every field to be returned anymore). What is the proper syntax to query this table in the exact manner as before, but with specifying the fields explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you just have to test it:

Without DISTINCT: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6805a/1

```
Value
A
A
B
B
```

With DISTINCT: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6805a/2

```
Value
A
B
```

And, as I've written in a comment, please don't create tables without a PRIMARY KEY... With a PRIMARY KEY clearly the two queries would be equivalent, because a PRIMARY KEY is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Example, you have these in your table

```
one
one
two
three
three
```

1 `select * from table1 t1` result:

```
one
one
two
three
three
```

2 `select distinct t1.* from table1 t1` result:

```
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 0):

As user Siyual mentioned in the comments to the question,

> DISTINCT works across the entire row, not for individual columns.

This was exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: This is not strictly true. Distinct works against the columns specified in the query, So distinct last_name would get you different results than distinct last_name, first_name when selecting from the same table. Of course, you should not use select distinct * as that is a SQL antipattern and if you have PK on the table as all tables should have, it will not filter any results as each record would be unique.